# How to fix "Stop running this script?" alert on this code?

Tags: javascript, devexpress

While running this code it shows alert. `filtereditem` is DevExpress listboxcontrol.
existingItems is an array with 247 items.

```
function GetMessage(){
    var deletedItems = '';
    var count = existingItems.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        var item = existingItems[i].text;
        if (!filtereditem.FindItemByText(item)) {
            if (deletedItems != '') {
                deletedItems = deletedItems + ', ' + item;
            }
            else {
                deletedItems = item;
            }
        }
    }
    return deletedItems;
}
```

Comment: How large is `count`? What is `FindItemByText()` doing?

Comment: FindItemByText() is client side method exposed by devexpress's listbox control, used to check existence of text.

Comment: It sounds like the script is running for way too long, can you use a jScript debugger to see why each iteration of the loop is taking so long, 247 loops is not a huge amount of iterations but if that FindItemByText is quite intensive then that would probably be the problem.

Comment: The usual solution to a long-running loop is to restructure the code using `setTimeout()`, with a callback for when the timeout-based "loop" finishes.

Comment: May be related: the process you're using to collect deletedItems may be quadratic-time, assuming string concatenation's implemented in a standard way.  Use an array and use its join method, rather than the piecemeal string concatenation.  E.g. ['hello', 'world'].join(', ')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all for valuable suggestion.

I am able to fix this, issue is with **FindItemByText()** methos, i replace it with **FindItemByValue()** and now its working fine.

Answer (score 2):

The "Stop running this script?" alert is typically triggered because some of your script code is taking a long time to execute.

Assuming that the alert is triggered by an invokation of the `GetMessage` function you've given the code for, I can offer you the following suggestion:

You have a `for` loop in this function.  There are three distinct reasons that this could be taking a long time.

1) Each iteration of the loop could be taking a long time.

2) There could be too many iterations so that even though each iteration takes only a short time, the entire loop takes a long time to execute.

3) It could be that although most iterations of the loop take only a short amount of time to execute, there could be some value of your looping variable `i` for which the code inside the loop freezes or takes a very long time.

You can use the JavaScript `getTime()` method to aid yourself in determining which of these three cases you're dealing with. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp